# ASP.net Hidden Field null in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

have a question about referencing an

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="editcheck" runat="server"/>
```

from a JS function. 
The function is being hit as a null reference error is thrown by the

```
var e = document.getElementById('<%=editcheck.ClientID%>');
```

line in the function.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

ps:
 Here is the actual line throwing the exception.

```
 if(e.value == "true")
     return confirm("yadayad");
```

The error states value can not be checked on a null object, or something close. So that is why I'm asking about the JS function seeing the element.

Comment: That particular line cannot throw null reference in JavaScript land unless `document` is null, which is unlikely. Is this the real code? What variable exactly is null?

Comment: Actually, you are correct. the exception is on the following line where I check for value. but when I hover over the element variable 'e' the debugger also shows null. Here is the actual line throwing the exception. `if(e.value == "true") return confirm("yadayad");` It error states value can not be checked on a null object, or something close. So that is why I'm asking about the JS function seeing the element. Thanks.

Comment: the line did not make it into the comment. anyway, please edit it into the question, since it is an important part of it.

Comment: When and how is your JavaScript code that throws the exception called?

Comment: `var e = document.getElementById('<%#editcheck.ClientID%>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you call the script before HiddenField is rendered to the browser.

Could you ensure that script is called after the HiddenField?

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="editcheck" runat="server"/>

document.getElementById('<%=editcheck.ClientID%>');
```

***OR*** you can use jQuery which is a lot easier if you have to manipulate with DOM. The following script doesn't matter where you place the HiddenField in the page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if ($("#<%= editcheck.ClientID %>").val() === "true") {
            return confirm("yadayad");
        }
    });
</script>        
<asp:HiddenField ID="editcheck" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Hmm, you may be on to something. I am registering the function from the master page. though I call it from an onClientClick of a button on the actual page., Maybe I should try re-registering it on page_Load event of the page? I'll get back with you. Thanks!

Comment: Nope re-registered it in page_load. no difference. I could try putting the script in the page but. I have not had to do that with other scripts. but for grins and giggles I'll move it.

Comment: I added the jQuery script, and see it help.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I've moved my script to the page itself. I get script undefined errors. Then I pasted your script in place of mine. Still getting script undefined.

Comment: Ok. You might want to debug step-by-step. First of all, you want to create a standalone aspx page without master page, and paste jQuery script including jquery.min.js.

Comment: Well I got the function to work by doing that Win. Thanks for the advice. I'm going to mark it as done. I still have to figure out where I'm breaking things. so next step is to move it back to the actual page. Again thanks for the debug reminders!